# rectangle drawn in different point when canvas is zoomed

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, rectangles

I have a canvas which has a zooming function. There are a lot of elements inside of it so, for selection I was going to use a selection box which I create dynamically when selection box is clicked. On clicking the button, I add  the rectangle to the canvas and again, on clicking the button, I remove it. 
I have the following xaml code:

```
<Viewbox x:Name="vbCanvas">
            <Grid x:Name="theGrid"
                  MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown"
                  MouseUp="Grid_MouseUp"
                  MouseMove="Grid_MouseMove"
                  Background="Transparent">

                <Canvas Name="canvasWaSNA" Margin="0,10,10,10" Height="720" Width="1280">

                </Canvas>
            </Grid>
        </Viewbox>
```

mouse events of `theGrid` draws the rectangle on runtime on the canvas. The codes for those events are:

```
bool mouseDown = false; 
Point mouseDownPos;
Point mouseUpPos;
private void Grid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
            mouseDown = true;
            mouseDownPos = e.GetPosition(theGrid);
            theGrid.CaptureMouse();
            // Initial placement of the drag selection box.         
            Canvas.SetLeft(sBox, mouseDownPos.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(sBox, mouseDownPos.Y);
            sBox.Width = 0;
            sBox.Height = 0;

            // Make the drag selection box visible.
            sBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }

    private void Grid_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
            // Release the mouse capture and stop tracking it.
            mouseDown = false;
            mouseUpPos = e.GetPosition(theGrid);

            theGrid.ReleaseMouseCapture();

            // Show the drag selection box.
            sBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            MessageBox.Show(mouseDownPos.ToString() + " " + mouseUpPos.ToString());

    }

    private void Grid_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
            if (mouseDown)
            {
                // When the mouse is held down, reposition the drag selection box.
                Point mousePos = e.GetPosition(theGrid);

                if (mouseDownPos.X < mousePos.X)
                {
                    Canvas.SetLeft(sBox, mouseDownPos.X);
                    sBox.Width = mousePos.X - mouseDownPos.X;
                }
                else
                {
                    Canvas.SetLeft(sBox, mousePos.X);
                    sBox.Width = mouseDownPos.X - mousePos.X;
                }

                if (mouseDownPos.Y < mousePos.Y)
                {
                    Canvas.SetTop(sBox, mouseDownPos.Y);
                    sBox.Height = mousePos.Y - mouseDownPos.Y;
                }
                else
                {
                    Canvas.SetTop(sBox, mousePos.Y);
                    sBox.Height = mouseDownPos.Y - mousePos.Y;
                }
            }

    }
```

To create a Rectangle at runtime, I have to click a button. The event of that button is as follows:

```
private void select_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

            if (!canvasWaSNA.Children.Contains(sBox))
            {

                sBox.Name = "selectionBox";
                sBox.StrokeThickness = 1.5 / zoomfactor;
                sBox.StrokeDashArray = new DoubleCollection { 1, 2 };
                sBox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
                sBox.Stroke = Brushes.Gray;
                canvasWaSNA.Children.Add(sBox);

        }
        else
        {
            sBox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            canvasWaSNA.Children.Remove(sBox);

        }
    }
```

I am using the following code to zoom into the canvas:

```
double zoomfactor = 1.0;
    void window_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        Point p = e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(canvasWaSNA); //gets the location of the canvas at which the mouse is pointed

        Matrix m = canvasWaSNA.RenderTransform.Value;
        if (e.Delta > 0)
        { //the amount of wheel of mouse changed. e.Delta holds int value.. +ve for uproll and -ve for downroll
            m.ScaleAtPrepend(1.1, 1.1, p.X, p.Y);
            zoomfactor *= 1.1;
        }
        else
        {
            m.ScaleAtPrepend(1 / 1.1, 1 / 1.1, p.X, p.Y);
            zoomfactor /= 1.1;
        }

        canvasWaSNA.RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform(m);
    }
```

When my canvas is on original size, The rectangle is drawn perfectly but as I zoom in or zoom out, rectangle is drawn abnormally. It starts to draw from other points. What might be the problem? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I wasnot supposed to capture the mouse position with respect to `theGrid`, as I had to create the rectangle with respect to canvas. So, I have to get the position as `e.GetPosition(canvasWaSNA)` and the intended result was shown. It captured the mouse position on the canvas. Now, the rectangle is drawn perfectly even when zoomed in or zoomed out.
Also, I improved the `StrokeThickness` of the rectangle drawn by referencing it with the zoomfactor of the canvas.

```
private void Grid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {mouseDown = true;
            mouseDownPos = e.GetPosition(canvasWaSNA);
            theGrid.CaptureMouse();
            sBox.StrokeThickness = 1.5 / zoomfactor;

            // Initial placement of the drag selection box.         
            Canvas.SetLeft(sBox, mouseDownPos.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(sBox, mouseDownPos.Y);
            sBox.Width = 0;
            sBox.Height = 0;

            // Make the drag selection box visible.
            sBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
```